# NSOutlineView - how does it get called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

In an NSTableView, there is a method called reloadData.

Is there something similar in an NSOutlineView? I am using an NSOutlineView without a tree controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView`, so all table view methods also work for an outline view.

Comment: Oh ic, so all the method that were used in an NSTableView can be used here as well. Thanks for the answer.